# File path for image in a different folder

Tags: html, css, path

I am currently in view.html, and trying to get to SIG_declaration.jpeg:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF8BD.png)

I have tried all i can think off

```
<img src="//subcontractors_docs//subcontractor_3//SIG_declaration.jpeg" alt="" width="600" height="150">
```

```
<img src="/subcontractors_docs/subcontractor_3/SIG_declaration.jpeg" alt="" width="600" height="150">
```

```
<img src="/../subcontractors_docs/subcontractor_3/SIG_declaration.jpeg" alt="" width="600" height="150">
```

```
<img src="/../../subcontractors_docs/subcontractor_3/SIG_declaration.jpeg" alt="" width="600" height="150">
```

```
<img src="../subcontractors_docs/subcontractor_3/SIG_declaration.jpeg" alt="" width="600" height="150">
```

```
<img src="/././subcontractors_docs/subcontractor_3/SIG_declaration.jpeg" alt="" width="600" height="150">
```

even known /../../ would in theory work, or just /sub... taking me back to the root directory. Nut all I get is a broken link, not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Follow the documentation for the framework that you're using (Django? Flask? ...).

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there, except that you don't want the opening `/`:

```html
<img src="../../subcontractors_docs/subcontractor_3/SIG_declaration.jpeg">
```

This is a relative path, though, and ideally you do want a root-relative path (that is, with an opening `/`). However, you have to make sure your local server has this set up, as otherwise the default is to point to the real root of your OS. (I assume this is something you're testing locally?)

Comment: Yes I am testing locally and I have tried this again and it still doesn't work, its a broken link. Thank you though

Comment: It works if I move it into my static folder, but I has hoping to have it in the subcontractor one